# Is a std extensions to insert or update kotlin mutable list which use Comparator?

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of complex objects and I want to merge this list with new one. But if in new one has same object (based on passed comparator) then element should be replaced otherwise added at end of list in order.

I wrote a extension function which do the job but I'm looking for more efficient way (and more elegant) like some combination of already existing extensions.

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.insertOrUpdate(items: List<T>, comparator: Comparator<T>): List<T> {
    val out = mutableListOf<T>()
    val toInsert = items.toMutableList()
    forEach { oldItem ->
        var wasUpdated = false
        items.forEach { newItem ->
            if (comparator.compare(oldItem, newItem) == 0) {
                out.add(newItem)
                toInsert.remove(newItem)
                wasUpdated = true
            }
        }
        if(!wasUpdated){
            out.add(oldItem)
        }
    }

    out.addAll(toInsert)

    return out
}
```

Comment: Use a `LinkedHashSet` (which iterates its elements in the order they were inserted) instead of a `List`, and simply `addAll()`?

Comment: @gidds and how to pass comparator?